# MVC Attribute routing and int 0 results in 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, windows-server-2012

I have an app for tracking tickets and time on tickets.

Within that app I have a time controller that will show all time entered.

```
[Authorize]
[RouteArea("Work", AreaPrefix = "")]
[RoutePrefix("Company/{companyId:int}/Client/{clientId:int}/Ticket/{ticketId:int}")]
public class TimeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    [Route("Time")]
    public ActionResult Index(int ticketId, int clientId, int companyId)
    {
        if (ticketId == 0)
        {
            var work = db.Time
                .Include(c => c.Ticket)
                .Where(c => c.Ticket.ClientId == clientId)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
                .ToList();
            return View(work);
        }
        else
        {
            var work = db.Time
                .Include(c => c.Ticket)
                .Where(c => c.TicketId == ticketId)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
                .ToList();
            return View(work);
        }
    }
```

If I pass a ticketId, it will filter all work related to that ticket.

http://somedomain.com/Company/1/Client/1/Ticket/1/Time

When I want to see all work related to the client (not ticket specific) I will pass a 0 for the ticketId such as:

http://somedomain.com/Company/1/Client/1/Ticket/0/Time

When I run this in Visual Studio debugger and local IIS it works perfectly.

When I publish this to the production server, the 0 will result in a 404 page not found.

Any ideas on what could be the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the method?

Comment: I updated with full code

Comment: Do other routes work in production? Is it IIS on production?

Comment: Every other controller and route works perfectly.  This is the only one that throws the 404 when changing to 0 on production.

Comment: Just a side note.  This app has been in production use for quite some time now.   No issues.  I just made this update today so I can see time on a client basis vs ticket.   It is the first issue I have ran into and it only pertains to that 0.  As far as I can tell it is specific to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel like an idiot.  I found the problem.

In my index view, I had an html.action (ChildActionOnly) that grabbed and displayed the ticket name at the top.  When the ticketId was 0, it resulted in not found.

I change it to:

```
@if (ViewBag.TicketId > 0)
{
   Html.Action("GetName", "Ticket", new { Area = "Ticket" });
}
```

And it worked just as expected.